# How can I extract just the IP Address out of the chrome Network Interfaces API?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to display the IP Address of the machine in HTML by using the Chrome Network Interfaces API. Here is the Javascript:

```
chrome.system.network.getNetworkInterfaces(function(address){
    console.log(address);
  });
```

And the place I'm trying to display it in (HTML)

```
<div id="fetch" class="ip"></div>
```

When my function logs the `address` property, it logs the entire array. How do I extract just the IP Address? The array looks like this:

```
Array(13)
0: {address: "[IP Address]", name: "arcbr0", prefixLength: [Integer]}
1: {address: "[IP Address]", name: "arc_eth0", prefixLength:  [Integer]}
2: {address: "[IP Address]", name: "arc_wlan0", prefixLength:  [Integer]}
3: {address: "[IP Address]", name: "eth0", prefixLength:  [Integer]}
4: {address: "[IP Address]", name: "wlan0", prefixLength:  [Integer]}
.......
length: 13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this example. Hope It works.

```
var address = {address: "[IP Address]", name: "arcbr0", prefixLength: 12};
for (let value of Object.values(address)) {
  alert(value); 
}
```

Comment: the console gives me this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: address is not defined" at this line 
`var IP = objects.address;`

Comment: Yes, it just gave me this error Error handling response: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: Yes, it just gave me this error again: Error handling response: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) My code looks like this now: `chrome.system.network.getNetworkInterfaces(function(address){ 
var objects = JSON.parse(address); 
var fetch = document.getElementById("fetch"); 
fetch.innerHTML = JSON.parse(objects.address); 
});`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210444/discussion-between-ahoop-and-suleyman-acar).